# Algorithm to find sum of 2nd,3rd and 4th highest numbers from 2 different arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have 2 very large integer arrays say a[] and b[].
I want to calculate the sum of 2nd, 3rd and 4th highest number from amongst a[] and b[].
i.e.  2nd, 3rd and 4th highest number amongst both the arrays...that is a sum of only 3 numbers.
Please suggest a good algorithm for this problem.

Please support your answer taking into account the time complexity of algorithm.

Note: Programming language is not a concern. You can assume C

Here is what i have developed for this problem
Algorithm:
1. Consider array a[] and b[]. Sort a[] and b[] with max heap sort.
2. Both the arrays are now sorted with max element as root node in both the arrays. Compare the root nodes of a[] and b[], whichever is bigger , delete that number from array.
3. Reheapify the array which had the max element.
4. Now add the root nodes from a[] and b[] in a variable say sum.
5. Reheapify a[] and b[].
6. Compare root nodes of a[] and b[], whichever is bigger add that number to sum.
7. Print the varibale sum.

Comment: What are **your** thoughts on this question?

Comment: this looks like the typical give-me-an-answer-for-my-homework-question.

Comment: You could create another array c[], sort it in decreasing order, then return c[1] + c[2] + c[3]. I don't think you can get much more efficient than that.

Comment: You don't have to sort to get the 4 highest numbers

Comment: Do you want the 2nd-highest of `a` plus the 2nd-highest of `b`, etc. or do you want the 2nd-highest of `a` plus the 3rd-highest of `a` and the 4th-highest of `a`, or something entirely different like the sum of all of them? E.g. imagine `A` and `B` are the sorted versions of `a` and `b`, respectively, do you want: 1) `{A[1]+B[1],A[2]+B[2],A[3]+B[3]}` 2) `{A[1]+A[2]+A[3],B[1]+B[2]+B[3]}`.

Comment: @Rafael Sorting is O(n log n); there exist more efficient algorithms than that depending upon what one precisely wants to do.

Comment: here is what i have developedAlgorithm:
1. Consider array a[] and b[]. Sort a[] and b[] with max heap sort.
2. Both the arrays are now sorted with max element as root node in both the arrays. Compare the root nodes of a[] and b[], whichever is bigger , delete that number from array.
3. Reheapify the array which had the max element.
4. Now add the root nodes from a[] and b[] in a variable say sum.
5. Reheapify a[] and b[].
6. Compare root nodes of a[] and b[], whichever is bigger add that number to sum.
7. Print the varibale sum.

Comment: @Girish, you should write in your question what you have so far, that way you show that you attempted something and are not just waiting for other people to do your homework.

Comment: @Girish: Please edit for that.

Comment: @minitech: 2nd, 3rd and 4th highest number amongst both the arrays...that is a sum of only 3 numbers

Comment: @Anders K: thanx for the suggestion....but i am looking for better algorithm than this....next time i will take care of that

Comment: Please do your own homework >.<

Comment: @Michael you're right: since the number of "sorted" elements needed is not dependent on the size of the array, a linear solution is possible. I retreat my previous statement in which I implied that a more efficient solution wasn't possible.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal and downvoters: Did this question receive as many downvotes as it did because it looks to you like homework or for other reasons?  If it is because it looks like homework, I should note that this type of problem is not some esoteric, only-in-homework type of problem.  I've needed to do very similar tasks in a professional environment before.

Comment: @Michael: Tagging as homework and downvoting are orthogonal.

Answer (score 5):

Since the arrays are not sorted, you have to go through every number at least once, so you have a low limit of O(n), where n is the total number of numbers. I believe you can do it in O(n).

Time: O(n)

Space: O(1)

```
int sum = 0;
int no1 = 0;
int no2 = 0;
int no3 = 0;
int no4 = 0;

int n =  a.size();

for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
{
   if ( a[i] >= no1 )
   {
      no4 = no3; no3 = no2; no2 = no1; no1 = a[i];
   }
   else if ( a[i] >= no2 )
   {
      no4 = no3; no3 = no2; no2 = a[i];
   }
   else if ( a[i] >= no3 )
   {
      no4 = no3; no3 = a[i];
   }
   else if ( a[i] > no4 )
   {
      no4 = a[i];
   } 
}

// Repeat the n =  a[].lenght; for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ){...}
// but using the b[] array instead of the a[]

sum = no2 + no3 + no4;
```

Sorting is inefficient since you only need 3 numbers, so why do the extra work?

Comment: This works in the specific case that you want 3 selections but does not generalize well beyond that.  Also the complexity might not be linear in n if the number of selections becomes nontrivial.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore You are not considering the fact that there are 2 arrays....this will work for 1 array only

Comment: Just to add that he has two arrays, to you'll have to iterate through 2 arrays.

Comment: @Girish The 2 array issue seems like a non-issue if you consider them as part of one larger array (whether you do this explicitly or implicitly).

Comment: @Micahel The problem essentially becomes complex because of 2 different arrays..this will work if we merge these 2 arrays into one....which will increase its complexity even more

Comment: Oh come on... just use 2 loops, time complexity is still O(n). Also, in this case we need 3 selections, so this solution suits the problem very well. Why the downvote?

Comment: @woliveirajr : the solution will probably work...but complexity is still an issue...

Comment: @Girish I don't think the 2 arrays aspect is material to the problem.  You can explicitly merge the arrays in linear time or you can implicitly do it: `int currentIndex = (i < a.length) ? i : i - a.length)`.  When `i >= a.length` you can look into b instead of a.

Comment: Really now, why the downvote? Why the need to over-complicate things? We need 3 numbers (not 5, not 1000), that's the problem. I really don't see what's wrong with my solution. Also, there are 2 arrays, yes, no need to merge them, just use 2 loops... Seriously?

Comment: @Girish - O(n) is the best complexity you can get since you have to check all numbers - the arrays are not sorted so you can't stop before you do. Sorting is O(n log(n)), so it's less efficient...

Comment: @Girish :  If you have to "visit" each array position only once, you'll be doing it in O(n) time complexity. Or, what do you mean by complexity ?

Comment: @Luchian I don't like your solution because it does **not** generalize to an arbitrary number of selections; you don't like my solution exactly because it **does** generalize to an arbitrary number of selections.  I believe we are at an impasse.

Comment: I don't like your solution because it's slower, not because it generalizes... If you can come up with a generalized answer that takes O(n), kudos to you... Otherwise, for the problem presented here, this is the best one so far...

Comment: @Luchian When you say slower, are you talking the naive solution that I started my answer with as an example of something that works that I do not recommend?

Comment: Mine is `O(n)`. And generalized.

Comment: The reason for my downvote is simply that I believe it's not a good answer since a better, simpler and more obvious one exists. The reason for your downvote is that mine can't be generalized. But that's not the point, since for the problem at hand, it's better than your solution. Downvoting a solution that's better than yours is a bit harsh, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @nulvinge agreed, I upvoted your answer. It's pretty much the same. I can generalize my solution also by using another for loop that iterates to 4 (or any other number). I just thought this was more readable and solves the problem at hand. Agree?

Comment: @Luchian Selection algorithms that I referenced can be done in O(n + k log k) where k things are being selected.  For k=3 that is negligible.  What the problem is asking for is exactly a selection algorithm, so I think it's harsh to downvote an answer mentioning selection algorithms.

Comment: In fact, if you want to find the maximum `k` numbers of an array, a similar algorithm to what is proposed here works best (with `O(kn)`). Note that here `k` is a constant so asymptotically, this is better than any `O(n^t) (t > 1)` or `O(nlogn)` etc. If `k` depends on `n` however, this is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 3):

`O(n)` in python:

```
def biggestn(n, array):
   arr=[]
   for x in array:
      arr=insert(arr,x)[0:n] #use insertion sort to insert x into arr here for speed 
   return sum(arr)
```

For two arrays just `biggestn(4, a++b)`

Comment: When you say `O(n)`, by `n` do you mean the length of the array or the actual `n` that you used?  Technically it depends on both, but it should be negligible here since the OP specifies only 3 elements.

Comment: Yes, I mean the length of array. It should be O(mlogn), where n is the n i used here, and m is length of array.

Comment: You need to see if you should keep it, thus you need to sort (e.g. compare it with some other number). This is kind of equivalent to @Lucians answer, but generalizes to any integer. Insertion sort has only `O(logn)` insertion time, which for n=4 should be considered `O(1)`. One could easily replace it with insert as I've done now.

Answer (score 1):

The naive solution (that I don't recommend) is to sort first and then add the 3 elements.  Assuming a reasonable sorting algorithm, this would be `O(n*log(n))`.

A better solution that generalizes to more than 3 elements would be to implement one of a number of [selection algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) based on selection sort or quicksort.  Depending upon what precisely one wants to do, these can approach linear time.

Comment: It depends on if you want to generalize to more than 3 selections.

Comment: don't need to sort the arrays if you just want to pick 3 numbers from it.

Comment: @ woliveirajr I'm not suggesting that you sort; I mentioned that sort as a way that works that is a bad idea.  Regardless, if you generalize above 3 then you want a selection algorithm.